# BigDecimal - comparing invariant to DecimalFormat

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I generate one BIgDecimal using a format ###,###.## which results in 660,000.00 and then I try to comapre it against a `new BigDecimal(660000.00)` but it returns false every time. Is there a way to compare the values invariant to the initial format they were created in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the *scale* of the two `BigDecimals` differ:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("660000.00").scale()); // 2
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(660000.00).scale());   // 0
```

To compare them regardless of scale, you could do:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("660000.00");
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(660000.00);

int s = Math.max(bd1.scale(), bd2.scale());
.. bd1.setScale(s).equals(bd2.setScale(s)) ..   // == true.
```

---

**A side-note:** Beware that a double literal, such as `.1` for instance, does not represent the real value .1, but an approximation of it. (This is due to inaccuracies in the floating point representation.) This can be seen by doing

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(.1));
```

which prints 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625

However, `new BigDecimal(".1")` does indeed represent exactly .1, which is why

```
new BigDecimal(.1).equals(new BigDecimal(".1"))
```

is false.

Comment: SO, any solution that would involve making scales the same?